# SQL select query - selecting from different fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table with the following columns: location, title and date.

I would like to search for the following

```
location = San Francisco OR Los Angeles
And
title = Hadoop OR Teradata
And
date = 21-5-2017 or 20-5-2017
```

Is that possible to do in one SQL query?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try writing the query same way? Did it work? Any error?

Comment: Are you really storing your dates as _text_ (`21-5-2017`)?  Don't do that, use a date column type.

Comment: No, just an example, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Query**

```
select * from `your_table_name`
where (`location` = 'San Francisco' or `location` = 'Los Angeles')
and (`title` = 'Hadoop' or `title` = 'Teradata')
and (`date` = '21-5-2017' or `date` = '20-5-2017');
```

Comment: @LironToval : Please mark it as answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Or, perhaps more elegantly...

```
select *
  from your_table_name
 where location IN ('San Francisco','Los Angeles')
   and title IN('Hadoop', 'Teradata')
   and date IN('2017-05-21', '2017-05-20');
```